# How to display images from sql server on webpage in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

How would I go about displaying images stored in varbinary(max) on a webpage? I have looked around and a lot of people recommend using the Image server control, but the images I am displaying are variable in number, so I'm not sure how I could use the control?

I also need to be able to resize and check the extension.

Comment: How are you accessing the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a generic handler for images (ashx) and in that handler I use response.binarywrite

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=193) is a good link that should get you started with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: +1.  Nice link to a fully documented article showing how to do it step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would make a page that would directly write the bytes from your DB to the response stream and then set the response content type to the appropriate image format. Example:

```
Response.Write(myDbByteArray);
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.End();
```

Then you would simply point images (even basic  tags) to your url:

```
<img src="Path/ToMyPage.aspx?imgId=1" alt="Some Image" />
```

As long as you return the right content type, it doesnt matter that the image tag source is an aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

Tejs give you the gist of it (ie. write the image into the response stream), but it left the interesting tidbits out. this article [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/streamingblobhttp.aspx) shows how to transfer images to and from SQL Server using efficient streaming semantics and no intermediate file. You should try to avoid getting the image into a `byte[]` as most solutions naively suggest, because it leads to tremendous memory consumption and does not scale.